# Upgrading Shimano Acera 8 speed Rear Derailleur to 8 speed Shimano XTR derailleur

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, compatibility, xtr

Looking for some help here. I am upgrading Shimano Acera 8 speed rear derailleur to 8 speed Shimano XTR rear derailleur and it appears that because the old 8 speed XTR derailleur has a clip for the tension of the b-screw that keeps the derailleur from sitting flush and looks like it is not compatible. What am I missing here? Is it a compatible swap?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Please add some clear pictures of both rear derailleurs with notations showing the interferences you are predicting.  Edit your question to add the images. This will help us out and help you get a meaningful, accurate, and useful answer that others can benefit from as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome - I imagine it would be fine, but definitely need a photo to show what you're up against.

Comment: thank you all i got it working the issue was with the crack alignment when i changed over to threespeed xtr hollowtech from the cheap octalink that came on the bike

Comment: @XTR23 Can you post that as an _answer,_ not a comment? It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question here.

Answer (score 0):

Many higher end Shimano derailleurs have had the circlip in question to allow disassembly and maintenance of the pivot bolt. RD-M900 (8-speed XTR) is one of those. In some (maybe all, not totally sure) of these designs the circlip will be the thing that rests against the frame, that's normal.